# Using Date Spinner in flex mobile application

Tags: android, apache-flex, datepicker

I am unable to use DateSpinner component in my flex mobile application. I am only interest to print date but not time. How can I achieve this in my flex mobile project. Platform is Flash Builder 4.6.

```
<s:HGroup verticalAlign="middle">
    <s:SpinnerListContainer>
        <s:DateSpinner id="dt"  /> 
    </s:SpinnerListContainer>
</s:HGroup>
```

The above code gives following error.
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.  DateSpinner.as:1290

Comment: Which version of the Flex SDK are you using?

Comment: Ther version of flex SDK is 4.6.0

Answer (score 0):

In the [example code](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DateSpinner.html#includeExamplesSummary) for the `DateSpinner` control, they are not wrapping it in a `SpinnerListContainer`. So perhaps that's your problem. Have you tried the `DateSpinner` by itself?

It appears to me that the `SpinnerListContainer` is intended to be used with a `SpinnerList` control. And that `SpinnerList` is for more generic lists, while `DateSpinner` is a stand alone component used specifically for dates/times.

Comment: But the following code doesn't work, when displaymode="date"

'<s:DateSpinner id="ds"
        selectedDate="{new Date(2010, 11, 15)}"
        minDate="{new Date(2000, 0, 1)}"
        maxDate="{new Date(2200, 11, 31)}"
        minuteStepSize="5" displayMode="date" />'

Comment: You're seriously passing in dates that go to the year 2200? Have you tried it w/dates that are from this century? And it's still not clear if you're wrapping this in a SpinnerListContainer as you show above. Instead of pasting your code into comments (which is hard to read), you can edit your question and show the actual code you're using :)

Answer (score 0):

The given code doesn't work when displayMode property is set to "date" only.

```
<s:DateSpinner id="ds"
selectedDate="{new Date(2010, 11, 15)}"
minDate="{new Date(2000, 0, 1)}"
maxDate="{new Date(2200, 11, 31)}"
minuteStepSize="5" displayMode="date" />
```

when I use `<s:DateSpinner id="dt" displayMode="dateAndTime" />` its works fine but it do not works when I set `displayMode="date"`

even the simplest form to dataspinner gives error, like you use

```
<s:DateSpinner id="ds" />
```

Answer (score 0):

i've the same problem. After debugging the as-code i found a problem with determine the textsize. So i look at my console output i found this warning: This component requires that the embedded font be declared with embedAsCFF=**false**.

Thereafter i configured my Font-Style:

```
@font-face {
src: url("assets/Sintony-Regular.ttf"); 
fontFamily: Sintony-Regular;
advancedAntiAliasing: true;
embedAsCFF: false;
embed-as-cff: flase;
font-lookup: embeddedCFF;
fontWeight: normal;
}
s|DateSpinner {
font-family: Sintony-Regular;
}
```

Now my DateSpinner works. But many other components gives the warning: This component requires that the embedded font be declared with embedAsCFF=**true**. It's not a fully solution, but a beginning. Mybe i have to use different font-face declarations.

Hope it works for you, too