# How to convert string in format DD/MM/YYYY to date object in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, date, flash-builder

I am taking date input from user in text field, which is in format DD/MM/YYYY. 
How to convert this string to date object in Flex. 
Platform: Adobe Flash Builder 4.6

Answer (score 3):

Since Flex SDK 4.10.0 you can use

```
DateFormatter.parseDateString(s, "DD/MM/YYYY");
```

Former versions of `parseDateString` didn't respect a format string, so it [cannot parse dateString value formatted with non default en_US format](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLEX-24225)

Comment: parseDateString existing in earlier versions of Flex but was improved in Apache Flex 4.9 and 4.10. Se release notes for both. There's a couple of fixes going into 4.11 mostly to do with dates formats without separators.

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateField's](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DateField.html) stringToDate method. DateFormatter also has a `parseDateString` function but for some reason it's set to protected.

```
  public function convertStringToDate(s:String):Date
  {       
       return DateField.stringToDate(s, "DD/MM/YYYY");
  }
```

Comment: I can't discover the exact version, but `parseDateString` isn't protected anymore at least since Flex 3.4. But this function shouldn't been used prior Flex SDK 4.10.0!

Comment: I am creating flex mobile application in Flash Builder 4.6. In which DateField object is not available. DateFormatter.parseDateString allows only one parameter.

Comment: Can you please answer this thread
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560650/using-date-spinner-in-flex-mobile-application]

Answer (score 0):

If you are not on the latest Apache SDK (I know we aren't because of third party components) you basically have to write your own conversion.

The built in DateFormatter has the static method, parseDateString, but you have no way of specifying the format of the string. It was a bit rubbish!

If you definitely have no localisation issues and are sure the date is ALWAYS in DD/MM/YYYY format you could use the following:

```
public function stringToDate(date:String):Date {
    // Extract year, month and day from passed in date string
    var year:int = IntFromSubString(date, 6, 4);
    var month:int = IntFromSubString(date, 3, 2);
    var day:int = IntFromSubString(date, 0, 2);

    // Always remember Flex months start from 0 (Jan=0, Feb=1 etc.) so take 1 off the parsed month
    return new Date(year, month-1, day);
}

private static function IntFromSubString(date:String, start:int, length:int):int {
    return parseInt(date.substr(start, length)) as int;
}
```